# implicit inheritance - how to remove boilerplate and code duplication

Tags: scala, inheritance, implicit

In the code example below there is quite a lot of code duplication. Is there any way to remove this ? I have been thinking about this for a while but still have no idea.

```
abstract class RouteBase[E <: Entity](
  )(
    implicit
    i:  ClassTag[E],
    en: Encoder[E],
    de: Decoder[E],
    sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
    ec: ExecutionContext)
{
   common concrete methods ...
   abstract methods ...
}

abstract class GetRouteBase [E <: Entity] (
    implicit
    i:  ClassTag[E],
    en: Encoder[E],
    de: Decoder[E],
    sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
    ec: ExecutionContext) extends RouteBase[E]
{
  implemented methods used by Get operations ...
}

class GetRoute[E <: Entity](
  )(
    implicit
    i:  ClassTag[E],
    en: Encoder[E],
    de: Decoder[E],
    sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
    ec: ExecutionContext) extends GetRouteBase[E]
   {  
     actual method implementations of all abstract methods ...  
   }
}
```

EDIT:

Interestingly this code compiles just fine:

```
class A {
  implicit val s:String = "bla"
}
class B  extends  A
{
  def printImplicit(implicit s:String)={
    println(s)
  }
  printImplicit
}
```

Comment: You can introduce a `case class Codec[E](enc: Encoder[E], dec: Decoder[E]) extends Encoder[E] with Decoder[E]`. (Similarly for other parameters if necessary, though I would not recommend.)

Comment: will that bring the implicits `enc` and `dec` into scope ? or how will that reduce code duplication ?

Comment: Would you prefer `E <: Entity: ClassTag: Encoder: Decoder`?

Comment: if you have an `implicit def codec: Codec[E]` somewhere, then sure, it will bring in scope, though you have to implement the traits in the `Codec` class.

Comment: Ok, I look into this.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how I can make the `Codec[E]` solution work...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an aggregate implicit context class and pass it. Using some stubs instead of the real types such as

```
type Entity = Object
type MyEntity = String
trait Encoder[E] {}
trait Decoder[E] {}
trait InterfaceToStateAccessor {}
```

You can create something like this:

```
@implicitNotFound("Make sure that you have implicit ClassTag, Encoder, Decoder, InterfaceToStateAccessor, and ExecutionContext visible here")
class RouteImplicitContext[E <: Entity](i: ClassTag[E],
                                               en: Encoder[E],
                                               de: Decoder[E],
                                               sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
                                               ec: ExecutionContext) {
  implicit val ii: ClassTag[E] = i
  implicit val ien: Encoder[E] = en
  implicit val ide: Decoder[E] = de
  implicit val isa: InterfaceToStateAccessor = sa
  implicit val iec: ExecutionContext = ec

}

object RouteImplicitContext {
  implicit def create[E <: Entity](implicit i: ClassTag[E],
                                   en: Encoder[E],
                                   de: Decoder[E],
                                   sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
                                   ec: ExecutionContext): RouteImplicitContext[E] = new RouteImplicitContext[E](i, en, de, sa, ec)
}
```

and then you may use it as

```
abstract class RouteBase[E <: Entity]()(implicit ctx: RouteImplicitContext[E]) {

  def doSomethingStrange(e: Entity)(implicit i: ClassTag[E],
                                    en: Encoder[E],
                                    de: Decoder[E],
                                    sa: InterfaceToStateAccessor,
                                    ec: ExecutionContext): Unit = {
    println(s"e = $e; implicits: i = $i, en=$en, de=$de, sa=$sa, ec=$ec")
  }

}

abstract class GetRouteBase[E <: Entity](implicit ctx: RouteImplicitContext[E]) extends RouteBase[E] {
}

class GetRoute[E <: Entity]()(implicit ctx: RouteImplicitContext[E]) extends GetRouteBase[E] {

  import ctx._ // <- this is important for code to compile

  def callSomethingStrange(e: Entity) = {
    doSomethingStrange(e)
  }
}

def test(): Unit = {
  implicit val en = new Encoder[MyEntity] {}
  implicit val de = new Decoder[MyEntity] {}
  implicit val sa = new InterfaceToStateAccessor {}
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val gr = new GetRoute[MyEntity]()
  gr.doSomethingStrange("abc")
}
```

This code compiles and runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. I am not sure if code duplication can be reduced even more in this example.

```
trait T {
  implicit val s:String
  implicit val i:Int
}

trait A { T =>
    def printA(implicit s:String) = {println("A"+s)}
}


trait B extends  A
{ T=>
  def printB(implicit i:Int) = {println("B"+i)}
}

trait C extends  B
{ T=>
  def printImplicit(implicit s:String,i:Int)={
    println(s)
    printA
    printB
  }
}

class D(implicit s2:String,i:Int) extends C {

    printImplicit
}
```